# How to set custom post type on the front-end side

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, types

just started learning word press and custom post types. I can create one and add fields. The problem is calling them on the front-end part. I managed to do some simple post dynamically, but now i face problem i cannot solve, so i'm here asking for help.

First my goal was to make loop for all buttons and expanding text inside them. But my code is kinda weird because first button has  tag while others . So i decided not to waste time, because really important part that i want to be able to change from WP dashboard is 3rd button expansion (list and text inside).

I tried using this code: 
But it creates posts inside first button. I just need 3 posts(expanding texts) and the last one to be dynamical. I feel i'm close but i can't get there.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xm-12">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'paslaugos' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-center"><?php the_field( 'paslaugos1_text' ); ?></h4>
        <ul class="kinas-teatras">
          <li>scenarijaus rašymas</li>
          <li>scenarijaus rašymas komandoje
          (co-writing)</li>
          <li>scenarijaus traktuotės (treatment), sinopsio ir kitų tekstų rašymas</li>
          <li>scenarijaus redagavimas (script editing)</li>
          <li>giluminė scenarijaus analizė ir
          “gydymo” paslaugos (script doctor</li>
          <li>individualios/ kolektyvinės konsultacijos</li>
        </ul>
        <?php endwhile; $loop->reset_postdata(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My html code:

```
 <div class="container">
  <h2 id="Paslaugos" class="d-flex justify-content-center">Paslaugos</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xm-12">
<p>
  <a class="btn mygtukai" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">KINAS, TEATRAS</a>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xm-12">
  <button class="btn mygtukai" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">REKLAMOS, TV IR KITA</button>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xm-12">

  <button class="btn mygtukai" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample3">EDUKACIJA</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xm-12">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-center">KINAS, TEATRAS</h4>
        <ul class="kinas-teatras">
          <li>scenarijaus rašymas</li>
          <li>scenarijaus rašymas komandoje
          (co-writing)</li>
          <li>scenarijaus traktuotės (treatment), sinopsio ir kitų tekstų rašymas</li>
          <li>scenarijaus redagavimas (script editing)</li>
          <li>giluminė scenarijaus analizė ir
          “gydymo” paslaugos (script doctor</li>
          <li>individualios/ kolektyvinės konsultacijos</li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xm-12">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-center">REKLAMOS, TV IR KITA</h4>
        <ul class="TV">
          <li>idėjų ir koncepcijų generavimas</li>
          <li>scenarijų rašymas</li>
          <li>tekstų rašymas</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xm-12">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample3">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-center">EDUKACIJA</h4>
        <ul class="edukacija">
          <li>kūrybinio rašymo kursai</li>
          <li>scenarijaus rašymo kursai</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="pp">Teikiame rašymo paslaugas ir konsultacijas. Dirbame individualiai ir komandoje.</p>
        <p class="pp">Kviečiame mokytis pasakoti istorijas mūsų autorių
      organizuojamuose kūrybinio rašymo ir scenarijaus kūrimo
      kursuose.</p>
      <p class="pp">Kūrybinius užsiėmimus galime organizuoti ir pagal
      individualius užsakymus.</p>
      <p class="pp">Artimiausi kūrybinio rašymo kursai numatomi 2019 m. kovo mėnesį,
      daugiau informacijos FB puslapyje.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">

    <br>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly you may just need to move the `<div>` with class `card` inside your loop so the code outputs a card element for each post in the query.

```
<div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
  <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'paslaugos' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="card card-body">
        <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-center"><?php the_field( 'paslaugos1_text' ); ?></h4>
        <ul class="kinas-teatras">
          <li>scenarijaus rašymas</li>
          <li>scenarijaus rašymas komandoje
          (co-writing)</li>
          <li>scenarijaus traktuotės (treatment), sinopsio ir kitų tekstų rašymas</li>
          <li>scenarijaus redagavimas (script editing)</li>
          <li>giluminė scenarijaus analizė ir
          “gydymo” paslaugos (script doctor</li>
          <li>individualios/ kolektyvinės konsultacijos</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; $loop->reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```